# How to create array with variable number of items, then increment some of those items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building a javascript widget to help knitters determine the number of stitches to place between increases when faced with a pattern instruction that reads "Increase X number of stitches evenly across a row." The problem is described [here](http://tingtink.com/2013/01/increase-over-row/).

So far my code works as long as the result is an even number.

I am stuck trying to figure out how to make it work if the number isn't even. I think what I need to do is populate an array with the number of groups of stitches, then increment through the array, adding 1 to each group until there is no leftover.

But I can't figure out how to 
a) Populate an array with a variable number of items--e.g.: How many groups of stitches are there? I need that number of items in the array.
b) Store the number of stitches in each group in each item in the array
c) Add 1 to each item in the array until the leftover is 0.

I'm open to other approaches, too.

Here's the code I have thus far. I haven't added the if/else conditional yet, nor have I added the for loop. Any thoughts or ideas will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
$('#calculateIncrease').submit(function() {
//get the number of stitches in the row
var stitchesInRow = $('input#stitchesInRow').val();
//get the number of stitches to increase by
var increaseByHowMany = $('input#increaseByHowMany').val();
//add one to this number
var divideBy = parseInt(increaseByHowMany,10) + 1;
//divide the number of stitches in row by increase plus one
var stitchesBetween = parseInt(stitchesInRow,10)/divideBy;
var leftover = stitchesInRow % divideBy;
//if there is no leftover
//return the result
$('#howManyStitches').html("Put " + stitchesBetween + " stitches between each increase.");
//if there is a leftover
var stitchesPerGroup = Math.floor(stitchesBetween);
//take divideBy, which is also the number of groups of stitches
//create an array that contains the number of groups (divideBy)
var stitchesArray = new Array(divideBy);
//each array item populated by the integer that is the first half of the division
//for each array item, add 1 until leftover = 0
//there should be some groups that get one added and others that do not
return false;
});
```

Comment: so your question seems to be how to populate an array with an arbitrary number of items? right? use Array.push in a loop then.

Comment: What kind of output do you have in mind in the leftover-case, since one output-number is then not possible right ? I read your site by the way and understand your question. Your current idea works when you are knitting a sawl, but what about a sleeve from a sweater?

Comment: The way it works in knitting is that you add one stitch to each group of stitches until your leftover is gone. So for example, if you have 17 sts on the needle and need to increase by 4 over the row, the result of the arithmetic is 3.4; or, 3 with a leftover of 2.

What a knitter would do is add one to each set of stitches until the leftover was gone. The resulting array in this example:

4,4,3,3,3

So, that's what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you for your thoughtful response, @GitaarLab. I'll take a look and see if I can make it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question as it is currently formulated (akonsu already answered the question's title in his comment) and also does not talk directly about that question.

However since I understand what she is trying to accomplish (and she's open to other approaches), I think that this is essentially a really good question,
so I'm posting this to aid other people in understanding what she really wants to accomplish with the code she posted and to help her define in more detail what the algorithm variation and end-result/output could/should be.

She wants to evenly distribute **x** number (of extra stitches per row) as evenly as possible over **y** number (of stitches that where on the previous row).

[image: img]

Her current base formula is: `y/(x+1)`
including rounding that would result in:

```
----------      10 stitches
-----+-----     add 1, every 5
---+----+---    add 2, every 3.3333
---+--+---+--   add 3, every 2.5
--+--+--+--+--  add 4, every 2
--+-+--+--+-+-- add 5, every 1.6667
```

A working [example (in jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/RrEd9/2/) could look like:
**Javascript**:

```
function handler(){
  var i, d=document,                                    //saving some code
      base=Number(d.getElementById('base').value),      //get row input
       add=Number(d.getElementById('add').value) + 1,   //get stitches to add
       ret='',          //return var
       tmp=0,           //temp var
       crr=0,           //carry var
       per=base/add;    //calculate period

  for (i = 1; i < add; i++) {   //start at 1 instead of 0
    tmp=Math.round(i * per);    //round first period
    ret+=tmp-crr+' + ';         //first period with previous period
    crr=tmp;                    //carry period
  }
  ret+=Math.round(add * per)-crr;          //last normal stitches
  d.getElementById('out').innerHTML=ret;   //output result
}
```

**HTML:**

```
Stitches on row: <input type="text" 
                          id="base" 
                       value="10"
                    onchange="handler();"
                 >
<br>
Stitches to add: <input type="text" 
                          id="add" 
                       value="1"
                    onchange="handler();"
                 >
<br>
<button onclick="handler();">calculate</button>
<br>
  Every + is a extra stitch: <br>
<div id="out">&nbsp;</div>
```

I think that would work as she currently expects it to.
However, I think one could then find a pattern in that, and I have no idea how to do that in a simple way. **Anyone?**

But I *think* this would only work for something that only goes from left to right, and not in a circle like a sleeve of a sweater. Then she might need something that looks a little more like a 'carousel':

'Carousel' style (formula: `((y+x)/x)-1`):

```
----------      10 stitches
----------+     add 1, every 10
-----+-----+    add 2, every 5
---+----+---+   add 3, every 3.3333
--+---+--+---+  add 4, every 3.5
--+--+--+--+--+ add 5, every 2
```

As you can see, the distribution is then different.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually, the increase would work the same way whether one were knitting in the round or knitting flat, because you'd want to add the stitches over one round rather than one row.

Comment: Thank you, you are welcome! PLEASE NOTE: I had a small error in the script: replaced "crr=0;" with "crr=0," this has been corrected in the jsfiddle and the code placed in my answer.

Comment: And I just accepted the answer. Thank you very, very much. I am deeply appreciative of the time you put into this. I learned a lot!